Python function default values are being automatically overridden
I am working on an interface with a bunch of QtWidgets that are meant to work together in various ways, oftentimes interacting with each other. In one area, I have a QLabel that can have its text and font manipulated by several other controls -- and in this instance, I am wanting to make a QDial that can change the font size of the label.
However, the issue that I encounter is that when I adjust the dial to increase/decrease the size of the font in the QLabel, the font of the label remains at 14pt font. This is despite the fact that I am taking the number value of QDial's .valuechanged.connect() slot and applying it as an argument to the function that is meant to adjust the font's type and size. Using a print(), I have noticed that every time I click the dial, it prints three lines: one with the dial's value and two with a value of 14.
The code I am working with is based on a template provided by PythonGUIs (see the "A Quick Demo" section). What I have done to the code (as an MRE) looks more like this:
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QDial, QFontComboBox, QLabel, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
)
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.fontcomboboxWidget = QFontComboBox()
        self.fontcomboboxWidget.currentFontChanged.connect(self.label_font_set)

        self.labelWidget = QLabel()
        self.labelWidget.setText("Hello world!")

        dialWidget = QDial()
        dialWidget.setRange(8, 96) # Set the range of font sizes
        dialWidget.setSingleStep(1)
        dialWidget.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_value_changed)

        self.label_font_set() # Sets the default font of labelWidget to 14pt Segoe UI
        # Removing this call does not fix the issue with the QDial.
        # Clicking the QDial or QFontComboBox simply sets the size to its default (14).

        # Add the widgets to the layout.
        self.layout.addWidget(self.fontcomboboxWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.labelWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(dialWidget)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def label_font_set(self, newFont = "Segoe UI", size = 14):
        print(f"Size is {size}")
        font = QFont(newFont)
        font.setPointSize(size)
        # We want to ensure that the QLabel is the same font as the QFontComboBox selection.
        self.labelWidget.setFont(font)
        self.fontcomboboxWidget.setCurrentFont(font)

    def dial_value_changed(self, number):
        self.label_font_set(size = number)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()

Notice how the dial_value_changed() function directly uses label_font_set() and is able to pass its number variable as an argument. However, as stated earlier, the output is always something to the extent of:
Size is 29
Size is 14
Size is 14

This proves that the size is being passed correctly, but something is calling label_font_set multiple times and overriding the value I set. This does not happen when changing the font with the QFontCombobox, which uses the same function but does not have an effect on size.
It seems the best solution would be to split the font type-setting functions and the font size-setting functions into two different areas, instead of putting them in one function.

The culprit is this line: self.fontcomboboxWidget.currentFontChanged.connect(self.label_font_set). When you change the font with the dial, the font in the combobox is changed and it calls label_font_set again without the size argument so the default is used.

That's a partial recursion, and one should always be careful in connecting signals to functions that have effect on the same object that would trigger the same signal, especially if those functions may be also called from elsewhere (as dial_value_changed() does). There is no absolute common solution for these situations, each case should be carefully considered, but in most cases (including this one) you can just avoid this by using with QSignalBlocker(self.fontcomboboxWidget): self.fontcomboboxWidget.setCurrentFont(font) which will set the font without making it emit the signal.
